# Omnichannel Flow - Routing to Agent Error

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, omnichannel

I've created an omnichannel flow (Chats routed to agent and queues).

The scenario was getting the end user number from the Messaging session and checking for cases associated to that end user number. If any cases matching to that number that will be routed to the case owner.

(Added Apex class to find the cases based on End user number). Added this apex class in the flow.
Here i'm getting the cases, issue was with the routing part. Getting the below error.

**Error Occurred: This Route Work invocable action did not create a valid Pending Service Routing.**

[image]

How to fix the above issue.